# Debugging an if statement with hasAttribute and offsetTop

Tags: javascript

Can someone help me debug why this if statement will not add a class list to translateX when the offsetTop = window.pageYOffset? There are no errors in the console so I don't understand why it doesn't work. If I just use classList to add the class when we start scrolling it works, but when I try to make it happen only once we get to a section with a data value on it it wont work.

Here is my javascript

```
const sections = document.querySelectorAll("section")
const clientTag = document.querySelector("h2.about")
const p02Tag = document.getElementById("p02")


document.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  const pixels = window.pageYOffset

  sections.forEach(section => {
    if(section.offsetTop - 400 <= pixels) {
      clientTag.innerHTML = section.getAttribute("data-client")

//this if statement is the one currently not working. 
      if (section.hasAttribute("data-seen-2")) {
      p02Tag.classList.add("move")
    } else {
      p02Tag.classList.remove("move")
    }

    }
  })

})
```

Css

```
div.work-info li.move {
  transform: translateX(20px);
}
```

HTML

```
  <div class="work-info">
    <ul>
      <li data-number="FN-UP Magazine" data-seen-1="yes"><a href=#">01<a></li>

      <li id="p02" data-number="Cameron Tidball-Sciullo" data-seen-2="yes"><a href="#">02</a></li>

      <li data-number="Jacob Truax" data-seen-3="yes"><a href="#">03</a></li>

      <li data-number="Alexander Romero" data-seen-4="yes"><a href="#">04</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <section class="work-page" data-client="FN-UP Magazine">
    <div class="content">
    <article class="col-1">
      <img src="lib/fn-up.png">
    </article>
    <article class="col-2">
      <img src="lib/fn-up.png">
    </article>
    <article class="col-3">
      <img src="lib/fn-up.png">
    </article>
    <article class="col-4">
      <img src="lib/fn-up.png">
    </article>
  </section>

  <section class="work-page" data-client="Cameron Tidball-Sciullo">
    <div class="content">
    <article class="col-5">
      <img src="lib/alex.png">
    </article>
    <article class="col-6">
      <img src="lib/alex.png">
    </article>
    <article class="col-7">
      <img src="lib/alex.png">
    </article>
    <article class="col-8">
      <img src="lib/alex.png">
    </article>

  </section>

  <section class="work-page" data-client="Jacob Truax">
    <div class="content">
    <article class="col-9">
      <img src="lib/old.png">
    </article>
    <article class="col-10">
      <img src="lib/old.png">
    </article>
    <article class="col-11">
      <img src="lib/old.png">
    </article>
    <article class="col-12">
      <img src="lib/old.png">
    </article>

  </section>

  <section class="work-page" data-client="Alexander Romero">
    <div class="content">
    <article class="col-13">
      <img src="lib/alex.png">
    </article>
    <article class="col-14">
      <img src="lib/alex.png">
    </article>
    <article class="col-15">
      <img src="lib/alex.png">
    </article>
    <article class="col-16">
      <img src="lib/alex.png">
    </article>

  </section>

  <footer class="footer">
    <h2 class="about">FN-UP Magazine</h2>
  </footer>

</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: theres no dom element that match `document.querySelectorAll("section")` in your html snippet...lets complete that

Comment: @NikkoKhresna updated the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `section` tag with an attribute `data-seen-2`, so the `if` clause never matches

```
if (section.hasAttribute("data-seen-2")) {
```

The only tag with that attribute is

```
<li id="p02" ... data-seen-2="yes"><a href="#">02</a></li>
```

Comment: Ah, wow. Such an easy fix haha can't believe I didn't notice that. Thanks!

Comment: Yup...the more detailed the problem is, it is actually half-solved already